How to set duration for spring type animationSpec in AnimatedVisibility?
How can I set the duration when spring type animationSpec is used in AnimatedVisibility?
AnimatedVisibility(
    enter = fadeIn(
        animationSpec = spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow)
    ),
    exit = fadeOut(
        animationSpec = spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow)
    ),
    ...
) {
    ...
}


In Jetpack compose, when using spring as a animationSpec, You don't directly set the duration because, spring animation is governed by physical properties like damping, stiffness, and mass rather than by duration.However, you can manipulate the animation's timing by tweaking the stiffness and damping ratio.
AnimatedVisibility(
enter = fadeIn(
    animationSpec = spring(
        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow,  // Lower stiffness for slower animation
        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioMediumBouncy // Adjust damping for bounce effect
    )
),
exit = fadeOut(
    animationSpec = spring(
        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessHigh, // Higher stiffness for faster animation
        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy // Less bounce for faster exit
    )
),

)
If you need precise control over timing, consider using tween or keyframes instead of spring, as they allow you to set a duration in milliseconds.
AnimatedVisibility(
enter = fadeIn(
    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000)  // 1 second duration
),
exit = fadeOut(
    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 500)  // 0.5 second duration
),)

